# Need to modify user attributes automatically when user attributes are changes in Oracle Directory Server Enterprise Edition(ODSEE)

Tags: ldap

I have OIM and ODSEE installed and LDAP Sync is enabled. In ODSEE, we have created custom object class and custom attributes. When user is created in OIM, LDAP Sync creates users in ODSEE with all attributes populated automatically. We have 2 custom attributes(Date attributes) specific to ODSEE like ghWhenCreated and ghWhenChanged which stores date values when user is created or modified in OIM. Currently we are populating these 2 attributes through event handlers in OIM. But we need these attributes to be populated automatically in ODSEE if there is add or modify requests in ODSEE since we are seeing issues when create/modification request happens in OIM. Does any one know how to update current date on custom attributes when soem entry is created or modified in ODSEE directly.

Let me know if you need further details.

Comment: Have you considered using the native operational attribute `createtimestamp` and `modifytimestamp` in ODSEE to determine when directory objects are really created and modified?

Comment: No. We don't want to use operational attributes as we have issue while retrieving these attributes from .net application and they are not visible automatically in LDAP client. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: that is odd. i would think this is the best practice in this realm. I suppose you could write a server side ODSEE plugin to copy those values to your own attributes.

Comment: ok. seems like thats the only option available for me. Thanks!